# Change the sharepoint icon for a site programmatically

Tags: sharepoint

I am needing to change the site icon for every site in a site collection in sharepoint 2007.  I already know you can change it from Site Settings -> Look and Feel.  Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean the site logo? Check out [SPWeb.SiteLogoUrl property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitelogourl.aspx). You probably want to set it as:

```
site.RootWeb.SiteLogoUrl = pictureUrl;
```

Comment: Don't forget site.Update() or web.Update()