# What is the best practice to change path to site logo for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have seen lots of demos and articles how to change site logo:

Site Action -> Site Settings -> Title Description and Icon... URL Address. Like this one:

**http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1e2MIEoBUs**

I guess this is a bad practice to use absolute URI to images because every time I migrate my site (from development to test, from test to productive environment) I will have to update absolute URI's manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use relative address to your custom logo file you can put you logo in SharePoint hive located in

> Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES

or put it in mapped folder {SharePointRoot}\Template\Images in Visual Studio Sharepoint project.

Then use the relative URL in Site Settings manually

> /_layouts/images/mylogo.gif

or programmatically by the site feature receiver [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969092/change-the-sharepoint-icon-for-a-site-programmatically)